# Is it possible to do webserver affinity in a Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a Docker container that is a REST API webserver.  I want to use this webserver in a Docker Swarm. A couple of the REST API calls are used in an asynchronous pattern.  That is, the first call provides data for processing, and is returned a request identifier.  The second call uses the request identifier to check on the processing and get the results when processing is done.  Since there is no connection between any of the webservers in the Docker Swarm, how can I force the second REST API call back to the Docker instance that was used in the first REST API call?  Is there anyway to ensure webserver affinity for these two REST API calls in a Docker Swarm?

Answer (score 1):

With Docker Swarm Mode and Ingress networking, connections are processed with round robin load balancing, and this isn't configurable. If the connection remains open, which is the case for most web browsers, you'll find that requests go back to the same instance.

You can use a reverse proxy in front of your application that is aware of each instance of the service. Docker has this with their HRM tool in the EE offering, and many of the other reverse proxies, like traefik, offer similar sticky session options.

If you can, a better design would be to utilize an external cache for any persistence, e.g. redis. This way you can perform a rolling update of your application without breaking all the sessions.

Comment: The Træfik reverse proxy approach just might be what I need. Thanks.